# Get Dates of a Certain Weekday from a Year in dart

Tags: datetime, mobile, flutter, dart

How might I generate a list of date objects for each Monday of a year?

i want like 
7 1 2019

14 1 2019

21 1 2019

...

4 3 2019

11 3 2019

blabla

Is there a function to do this in the DateTime library? i think i missed something,the same question asked for R but I really did not understand anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the function doesn't exist but you can try this code:

```
void main() {
  var givenYear = 1999;
  var listOfMondays = [];
  var dateIter = DateTime(givenYear);
  while (dateIter.year < givenYear + 1) {
    dateIter.add(new Duration(days: 1));
    if (dateIter.weekday == 1) {
        //1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, 3 for Wednesday and so on.
      listOfMondays.add(dateIter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I really dont want use like that, but i have to i guess Thanks man

Comment: I think one way or another you'll have to use iteration, optimization is up to you